# Get the origin x of the last UIButton in UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uibutton, frame, subview

I would like to know if it's possible to get the origin x of the last UIButton which is subview of an UIScrollView.

I tried this code, but it's not working because if I NSLog its frame it returns 0:

```
-(void)myMethod 
{
    UIButton *lastButton = [[toggleScroll subviews]lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Button frame %f", lastButton.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Button origin %f", lastButton.frame.origin.x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by “last”.  The order of the `subviews` array has nothing to do with the X/Y position of each subview on screen.  I assume you actually want the largest X coordinate of all of the buttons' origin X coordinates:

```
CGFloat xMax = -HUGE_VALF;
for (UIView *subview in toggleScroll.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        xMax = MAX(xMax, subview.frame.origin.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it able to get the max x value of the buttons in the UIScrollView, right ? So I tried: http://pastie.org/private/s7jxvb19oulraxzmn18dw But it doesn't add an UIButton after the "last UIButton" of the UIView.

Comment: It is clear from your example code that you need to spend some time learning the basics of C.